# Linux "drop box" alternatives

Tags: linux

What I'm basically needing is a drop box/SFTP server where I can create an account fairly easily and give the user the password and have him access some files and then delete him later. My main requirements are:

1. Free and runs on Linux
2. Is easier for people to get to (ex. go to http://example.com and put in username/password)
3. It is secure
4. It is capable of transferring large files

It doesn't have to do any AD/LDAP integration or anything like that. Just down and dirty local user account and secure transfer methods. I've looked around quite a bit and am still looking but would just like some personal opinions. Thanks.

Comment: check out sparkleshare

Answer (score 1):

What about ubuntus ubuntu one?

Theres also [deja dup](http://www.google.at/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=de&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=deja%20dup&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1&fp=7e5bb285645a0e64&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7e5bb285645a0e64&biw=1071&bih=949&ion=1) which supports syncing to any sftp server or amazon s3

But I personally just like to mount / access my folder over ssh/sftp.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found Openfiler but did not test it myself yet

http://www.openfiler.com

--
File-based networking protocols supported by Openfiler include: NFS, SMB/CIFS, **HTTP/WebDAV** and FTP. Network directories supported by Openfiler include NIS, LDAP (with support for SMB/CIFS encrypted passwords), Active Directory (in native and mixed modes) and Hesiod. Authentication protocols include Kerberos 5.

Sounds interesting

Comment: i tried it once, but liked freenas more. its more of a nas server software, i think the questionoaire is looking for a client program

Comment: Did you try their HTTP ? Browser is great client if they have HTTP with auth and nice UI

Answer (score 0):

we use ifolder for this purpose in my organization and it works great. iFolder is like dropbox but is open source, and you need to host it yourself. it requires OpenSusie 11.1

I've seen tuturials from people running it in Ubuntu as well.